# Is it possible to create a multi project template with references without a wizard?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I've looked at a couple of questions on stackoverflow and noticed that it seems like the only way to fix the references of a multi project template appears to be a  wizard. I've looked at the templates from microsoft, guides on VSSDK, tried $safesolutionname$ but none of the options really turned into paths which were correct (sub projects always inherited the current project name, so i was unable to force specific paths).

Is this still the case or am i not up to date here? Currently looking into patching things up using powershell if that is an option.

If anyone found a way to do things differently i would be very curious to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2017) after all.

I had to apply the following changes to get it working

- use $ext_safeprojectname$ in the sub projects
- add CopyParameters=true

[image: works like this]